# Spring Integration multiple UDP inbound/outbound channels

Tags: java, spring, udp, spring-integration

I am trying to build a module to be deployed on multiple nodes using Spring boot. Due to time constraints of the specific application, I have to use UDP and cannot rely on the easier-to-use REST facilities that Spring provides.

I have to be able to **send datagrams to a set of nodes that may vary in time** (i.e. the set may grow or shrink, or some nodes may move to new ip/port "coordinates"). Communication **must be unicast**.

I have been reading the official documentation about TCP and UDP support [TCP and UDP support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html), but it is rather... compact, and opaque. The javadocs on the org.springframework.integration classes are also rather brief for that matter. 
For what I could understand, an "inbound" channel is used to *send* a packet, while an outbound channel is used to *receive* packets.

I haven't been able so far to find an answer to the following issues for inbound (i.e. "send" channels, if I understood well):
 - How can I create more channels at runtime, to send packets to multiple destinations?
 - If a host gets moved, should I just destroy the channel and set up a new one, or may I change a channel's parameters (destination ip/port) at runtime?

For outbound channels ("receive" channels if I understood well), I have similar questions to the above, as in:
 - How do I set up multiple channels at runtime?
 - How do I change destination for an existing channel at runtime, not to have to tear it down and set it up anew?
 - Should I just open/close "raw" UDP sockets instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have inbound and outbound reversed.

Here's an example that should provide you with what you need; it uses a pub/sub channel to broadcast...

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So48213450Application {

    private final Map<Integer, IntegrationFlowRegistration> registrations = new HashMap<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So48213450Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public PublishSubscribeChannel channel() {
        return new PublishSubscribeChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(PublishSubscribeChannel channel) {
        return args -> {
            makeANewUdpAdapter(1234);
            makeANewUdpAdapter(1235);
            channel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("foo\n").build());
            registrations.values().forEach(r -> {
                r.stop();
                r.destroy();
            });
        };
    }

    @Autowired
    private IntegrationFlowContext flowContext;

    public void makeANewUdpAdapter(int port) {
        System.out.println("Creating an adapter to send to port " + port);
        IntegrationFlow flow = IntegrationFlows.from(channel())
                .handle(Udp.outboundAdapter("localhost", port))
                .get();
        IntegrationFlowRegistration registration = flowContext.registration(flow).register();
        registrations.put(port, registration);
    }

}
```

result:

```
$ nc -u -l 1234 &
[1] 56730
$ nc -u -l 1235 &
[2] 56739
$ jobs
[1]-  Running                 nc -u -l 1234 &
[2]+  Running                 nc -u -l 1235 &
$ foo
foo
```

You can't change parameters at runtime, you would have to create new ones.

**EDIT**

In response to your comments below...

You can't mix and match spring integration jars (2.1.x and 5.0.x); they must all be with the same version. My example above used Boot 2.0.0.M7 (boot 2 is scheduled to be released next month).

The Udp factory class was added to spring-integration-ip in 5.0.0.

Here is a similar example (which also adds receiving adapters) for boot 1.5.9 and spring integration 4.3.13...

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So482134501Application {

    private final Map<Integer, IntegrationFlowRegistration> registrations = new HashMap<>();

    @Autowired
    private IntegrationFlowContext flowContext;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So482134501Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public PublishSubscribeChannel channel() {
        return new PublishSubscribeChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(PublishSubscribeChannel channel) {
        return args -> {
            makeANewUdpInbound(1234);
            makeANewUdpInbound(1235);
            makeANewUdpOutbound(1234);
            makeANewUdpOutbound(1235);
            Thread.sleep(5_000);
            channel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("foo\n").build());
            this.registrations.values().forEach(r -> {
                r.stop();
                r.destroy();
            });
            this.registrations.clear();
        };
    }

    public void makeANewUdpOutbound(int port) {
        System.out.println("Creating an adapter to send to port " + port);
        IntegrationFlow flow = IntegrationFlows.from(channel())
                .handle(new UnicastSendingMessageHandler("localhost", port))
                .get();
        IntegrationFlowRegistration registration = flowContext.registration(flow).register();
        registrations.put(port, registration);
    }

    public void makeANewUdpInbound(int port) {
        System.out.println("Creating an adapter to receive from port " + port);
        IntegrationFlow flow = IntegrationFlows.from(new UnicastReceivingChannelAdapter(port))
                .<byte[], String>transform(String::new)
                .handle(System.out::println)
                .get();
        IntegrationFlowRegistration registration = flowContext.registration(flow).register();
        registrations.put(port, registration);
    }

}
```

result:

```
GenericMessage [payload=foo
, headers={ip_packetAddress=localhost/127.0.0.1:54881, ip_address=127.0.0.1, id=db7dae61-078c-5eb6-dde4-f83fc6c591d1, ip_port=54881, ip_hostname=localhost, timestamp=1515764556722}]
GenericMessage [payload=foo
, headers={ip_packetAddress=localhost/127.0.0.1:54880, ip_address=127.0.0.1, id=d1f79e79-569b-637b-57c5-549051f1b031, ip_port=54880, ip_hostname=localhost, timestamp=1515764556722}]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I haven't been able to actually use Udp.outboundAdapter(...). I think I may have some problem with my pom file (it's a maven project). The parent artifact is **spring-boot-starter-parent** (1.5.9 RELEASE), and for integration I have **spring-integration-core** (5.0.0 RELEASE) and **spring-integration-ip** (2.1.3 RELEASE). I'm using Java 8. What do I need to solve that dependency?

Comment: The `Udp` factory was added in s-i-ip 5.0. See the edit to my answer for a boot 1.5.9 version.

Comment: I found the missing packages, and now I managed to have it working. Thank you again. Marked as correct answer.