# Spring integration inbound adapter automatic port

Tags: java, spring, udp, spring-integration

Gary Russell kindly answered a [previous question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48213450/spring-integration-multiple-udp-inbound-outbound-channels) about Spring Integration udp flows. Moving from there, I have stumbled upon an issue with ports.

The [Spring Integration documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html) says that **you can put 0 to the inbound channel adapter port, and the OS will select an available port for the adapter**, which can be retrieved at runtime invoking *getPort()* on the adapter object. The problem is that **at runtime I just get a 0** if I try to retrieve the port programmatically.
Here's "my" code (i.e. a slightly modified version of Russel's answer to my previous question for Spring Integration 4.3.12, which I am currently using).

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class  TestApp  {

private final Map<Integer, IntegrationFlowRegistration> registrations = new HashMap<>();

@Autowired
private IntegrationFlowContext flowContext;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(TestApp.class, args);
}

@Bean
public PublishSubscribeChannel channel() {
    return new PublishSubscribeChannel();
}

@Bean
public TestData test() {
    return new TestData();
}

@Bean
public ApplicationRunner runner() {     
    return args -> {
        UnicastReceivingChannelAdapter source;
        source = makeANewUdpInbound(0);
        makeANewUdpOutbound(source.getPort());
         Thread.sleep(5_000);
         channel().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("foo\n").build());
         this.registrations.values().forEach(r -> {
           r.stop();
           r.destroy();
         });
         this.registrations.clear();

         makeANewUdpInbound(1235);
         makeANewUdpOutbound(1235);
         Thread.sleep(5_000);
         channel().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("bar\n").build());
         this.registrations.values().forEach(r -> {
           r.stop();
           r.destroy();
         });
         this.registrations.clear();
    };
}

public UnicastSendingMessageHandler makeANewUdpOutbound(int port) {
    System.out.println("Creating an adapter to send to port " + port);
    UnicastSendingMessageHandler adapter = new UnicastSendingMessageHandler("localhost", port);
    IntegrationFlow flow = IntegrationFlows.from(channel())
            .handle(adapter)
            .get();
    IntegrationFlowRegistration registration = flowContext.registration(flow).register();
    registrations.put(port, registration);
    return adapter;
}

public UnicastReceivingChannelAdapter makeANewUdpInbound(int port) {
    System.out.println("Creating an adapter to receive from port " + port);
    UnicastReceivingChannelAdapter source = new UnicastReceivingChannelAdapter(port);
    IntegrationFlow flow = IntegrationFlows.from(source)
            .<byte[], String>transform(String::new)
            .handle(System.out::println)
            .get();
    IntegrationFlowRegistration registration = flowContext.registration(flow).register();
    registrations.put(port, registration);
    return source;
}
}
```

The output I read is

```
Creating an adapter to receive from port 0
Creating an adapter to send to port 0
Creating an adapter to receive from port 1235
Creating an adapter to send to port 1235
GenericMessage [payload=bar, headers={ip_packetAddress=127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:54374, ip_address=127.0.0.1, id=c95d6255-e63a-433d-3723-c389fe66b060, ip_port=54374, ip_hostname=127.0.0.1, timestamp=1517220716983}]
```

I suspect the library did create adapters on OS-chosen free ports, but I am unable to retrieve the assigned port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The port is assigned asynchronously; you need to wait until the port is actually assigned. Something like...

```
int n = 0;
while (n++ < 100 && ! source.isListening()) {
    Thread.sleep(100;
}
if (!source.isListening()) {
    // failed to start in 10 seconds.
}
```

We should probably enhance the adapter to emit an event when the port is ready. Feel free to open an 'Improvement' [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT).

Comment: Thank you again, Mr. Russel.